# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want this procedure to copy the contents from lib_booksdist to lib_books but it keeps giving this error:

```
delimiter //
create or replace procedure add_batch()
begin
select count into @c from `lib_booksdist` group by book_insertedon having book_insertedon= max(book_insertedon);
set @i=0;
    while i < c do
        INSERT INTO `lib_books` (book_name, book_dept, book_sub, book_insertedby, book_insertedon)
        select book_name, book_dept, book_sub, book_insertedby, book_insertedon from `lib_booksdist`
        group by book_name
        having book_insertedon=max(book_insertedon);
        set @i=i+1;
    end while;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

The above code generates this error in MySQL(MariaDB).

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'
```

Comment: In `@i=i+1`, MySQL thinks i is the name of a column. Did you mean `@i=@i+1`?

Comment: tried it but it still gives the same error when the procedure is called

Comment: on the `while` the same (replace `i` with `@i` and `c` with `@c`)

Comment: Okay thank you  @SebastianBrosch that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO i figured it out there were 2 problem in the code in question

- In line 5: (`while i < c`) it should be `while @i < @c`
- In line 10: (`set @i=i+1`) it should be `set @i=@i+1`

thanks to all the comments helping me figure out this